# Regular Expressions: matching words keeping their case

Tags: python, regex

I have been given an assignment for my Python class and I have been tasked with the following:

- You need to think of three words you will be searching for in lines read in from the keyboard. The three words are your first name, your favorite color, and your favorite season.
- Your program will prompt the user for a line then you will use regular expressions to search the line for each of the words. You want to find the words even if case is mixed or different from what you normally use.
- If you find your first name you should print out the output, “Hey, my name is NAME.”  With NAME replaced with exactly what was typed (including case).
- If you find your favorite color you should print out the output, “Oh, I like the color COLOR.”  With the COLOR replaced with exactly what was typed (including case).
- If you find your favorite season you should print out the output, “I do think SEASON is the best season.”  With the SEASON replaced with exactly what was typed (including case).

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import re

input = raw_input("Please input a sentence stating your name, your favorite color, and your favorite season: ")

x = "My name is DoTNeT."
name = input.split(",")[1]
z = re.search(name, x)

if z == None:
    pass
else:
    print x
```

I think I have the right idea here... I know it's not right, I'm just frustrated because I am still learning Python and with that comes learning how to talk about it. I don't know how to accurately say WHY I'm wrong or how I need to fix it. I'm not looking for someone to just ANSWER this for me, I want to understand it.

Comment: You seem to be trying to search for `My name is DoTNeT` in the second "chunk" of input after a comma (you split by comma and then try to search for `My name is DoTNet` in the second of those chunks). Shouldn't you just be trying to look for `DoTNet` (case insensitive) in the input provided by the user? Meaning, your whole input is a text (a `str`, rather) and you need to find `DoTNet` in it?

Comment: whatever BorrajaX said. plus, if you have the right keywords try with re.match with re.IGNORECAS and re.sub

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you just need suggestions not actual code (I liked that). Here are few things that you might find helpful:

- Use [`string.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split your string into words ([Tutorial link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm))
- [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to check for substring and [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for replacing the string. 
  For example: `your_word` will check for `your_word` in string as:

  ```
  >>> import re
  >>> if re.search('hello', 'yes hello world'):
  ...    print 'match'
  ...
  match  # prints match as "hello" is present in "yes hello world"
  ```

Please read: [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) document. Specially [re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) for case insensitive search.

Comment: didn't he mean if `hEllo` is input `yes hello world` would be printed as `yes hEllo world`.

Comment: As he mentioned, he doesn't need the actual code. He wants to solve his problem by own. I am just showing him the path :)

Comment: :D I see. btw you don't need `.*` for re.search. It is needed for re.match.

Comment: I'm really sorry but this is all going way over my head. The link you provided was assigned reading for my class but it just feels like information overload.

Comment: Instead of just reading, play with the mentioned functions and see how they behave and are different from one another. Also, I have very limited the scope with specific functions that you'll need for this purpose. But it is good to check all the functions at least once

Comment: I just can't get my head around this. My teacher was patronizing and unhelpful. I hate to do this but can you just show me what you would do for this? I'm very frustrated, read countless documentation and experimented with everything I've seen and I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a pattern that matches any word from a list, using parenthesis and pipes. You could use this to match seasons and colors:

```
seasons = "(winter|spring|summer|fall)"
colors = "(red|white|black|yellow|pink|brown|green|blue|purple|cyan)"
```

As someone already mentioned, you can use the flag `re.IGNORECASE` to match a pattern with whatever case it was written. For example, for the seasons:

```
match = re.search("(winter|spring|summer|fall)", "i like SumMer")
print match.group()
# SumMer
```

Here I'm doing a [`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) with the seasons pattern on the string `i like SumMer`. Since there is a match it returns a `MatchObject`, and I'm doing `group` on it to get my group match, which is `SumMer`. If there is no match, `match` will be `None`.

If you don't know what I mean by groups, simply put, when you have parenthesis in your pattern you are creating a new group. The group `0` is your full match. Though you can have [non-capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) if you add `?:`. Take this example, where only the last group is non-capturing:

```
match = re.search("(hello|hi), my name is (paul|henri). (?:bye|goodbye)", "Hi, my name is HENRI. GoodBye", re.IGNORECASE)
match.group(0)  # Hi, my name is HENRI
match.group(1)  # Hi
match.group(2)  # HENRI
match.group(3)  # ERROR!
match.groups()  # ('Hi', 'HENRI')
```

Now, how do we match a name? This one is tricky, either you have a list of all possible names, or you consider that the name always comes after a sentence like `I'm`, `I am` or `My name is`. I'm going with the second choice and create a pattern like this:

```
names = "(?:my name is|i am|i'm) ([A-Za-z-]+)"
```

I have a non-capturing group with the phrases I just mentioned and then I'm creating a group of `[A-Za-z-]+`. Let's break this down (you can see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more details and more patterns):

- `[]` - matches set of characters or ranges
- `A-Z` - matches all letters in uppercase
- `a-z` - matches all letters in lowercase
- `-` - matches `-` literal
- `[A-Za-z-]` - matches all letters, in upper and lowercase and `-`
- `+` - matches the previous token repeated 1 or more
- `[A-Za-z-]+` - matches 1 or more letters or `-`

So now we try to match all of our patterns and put it all together:

```
import re
names = "(?:my name is|i am|i'm) ([A-Za-z-]+)"
colors = "(red|white|black|yellow|pink|brown|green|blue|purple|cyan)"
seasons = "(winter|spring|summer|fall)"

sentence = raw_input("Please input a sentence stating your name, your favorite color, and your favorite season: ")

# Check for name
name = re.search(names, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
if name:
    print("Hey, my name is {}".format(name.group(1)))

# Check for color
color = re.search(colors, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
if color:
    print("Oh, I like the color {}".format(color.group()))

# Check for season
season = re.search(seasons, sentence, re.IGNORECASE)
if season:
    print("I do think {} is the best season".format(season.group()))
```

When run:

```
>>> Please input a sentence stating your name, your favorite color, and your favorite season: I'm Jon Snow. Winter is coming along with the WHITE WALKERS.
Hey, my name is Jon
Oh, I like the color WHITE
I do think Winter is the best season
```

If you have any question, do not hesitate. Coding is fun, do not lose hope :)